# Where does GA tracking data go when wrong domain at _domainname is set?

Tags: google-analytics

I improperly set the the _domainname value for a couple of weeks.

The UA code was set properly.

Prior to the improper setting of _domainname all data was being captured correctly.

Where will the data have gone during the couple of weeks the setting is incorrect?

Is it possible to retrieve this data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_setDomainName](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#-_setdomainname) sets the domain for the cookies.

> Sets the domain name for the GATC cookies. There are three modes to
>   this method: ("auto" | "none" | [domain]). By default, the method is
>   set to auto, which attempts to resolve the domain name based on the
>   document.domain property in the DOM.

It can be used e.g. that a cookie only is set for a certain subdomain, or just for the main domain, plus it's used in cross domain tracking. It is not usually necessary for tracking a single domain.

If you have set a wrong value for the cookie domain Google Analytics cannot set a cookie and the tracking call will fail.

So the data has **not been send at all**, and you cannot retrieve it.